# Run Vite + React in docker with Hot Module Reload

Tags: docker, vite, hot-module-replacement

Currently, I am working on a project with Vite + React and now I want to dockerize it. Actually, I am beginner to Docker. So, I need guidance on how to build the Docker image and run it.

I tried once and it worked, but not as I supposed.

Can anyone help me with following,

- How to dockerize the React app with Vite?
- How to run the webapp on local host when developing?
- Hot Module Reload tool in Vite didn't work for me, how to fix it?

I used following commands in cmd:
`docker build .`
and
`docker run -p 5173:5173 0ac94edb8feb`

And here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Give me instructions to fix above issue.

Comment: You can use normal host-based tools like `npm run dev` while you're working on an application, even if you're eventually going to deploy it in Docker.  The Dockerfile looks fine, but since Docker is an isolated environment, the container can't see your code edits on the host.  The most common approach to this involves replacing absolutely everything in the container with host content, at which point you're not really "Dockerizing the application" so much as working on your code with tools in an inconvenient place.

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you explain it more. I am new to docker, that's why. I would be better you can explain it using codes also.

Comment: Maybe I should ask, why are you trying to use Docker here?  "Isolated immutable deployments" and "live reloading developer setup" are pretty different use cases, and Docker is much better at the first than the second.  You also might search for existing questions on this use case, since it seems to come up pretty frequently.